# Urban fantasy book about magic appearing in the modern world

Tags: story-identification, books, urban-fantasy

This is an urban fantasy book in which magic suddenly returns to the modern world. The setting is in a large city (maybe New York) and has a very disaster-genre feel. The protagonist's boss is slowly turning into a dragon. This would have been in the late 90s, I think.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Not the story you're looking for, but you might check out the Kate Daniels series by Ilona Andrews. It's set in post-magical-apocalypse Atlanta, but the series is more modern and there are no dragons or bosses like the one you described.

Comment: The rough bones of it sounds like the Shadowrun setting, but I don't know about those details. Edit: Taking a glance through a list and brief synopsis, *Never Deal With A Dragon* sounds promising.

Comment: @Radhil a Shadowrun RPG tie-in was my first thought too

Comment: @Moriarty - Honestly I've only ever read *Changeling*, but it feels right.

Comment: No one would turn into a Dragon in Shadowrun, right? Trolls or orcs or something humanoid, but if their boss turns into a dragon then their boss was always a dragon.

Comment: @Adamant - if I understand right, dragons have a human form or disguise.  Might not seem too different to a fuzzy memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the ["Magic Time" series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/60086-magic-time) by Marc Zicree and a different collaborator for each book (Barbara Hambly for the first book, which is why I picked it up). It has been many years since I read it, but IIRC, a lot of modern technology stopped working, so it was definitely a disastrous/apocalyptic setting, and there was someone who turned into a dragon.

> For rising young lawyer Cal Griffin, it's just another day in the Big City--until the lights go off...for good. Suddenly packs of pale crouched figures are stalking the darkened subways, monsters prowl Times Square, and the people all around Cal are...changing. Similar weirdness is happening everywhere, from the dank, cold heart of a West Virginia coal mine to a remote lab in South Dakota--where a team of government scientists has unwittingly invited something catastrophic into the world--to the highest levels of power in Washington, D.C. And Cal Griffin is not the only one struggling to comprehend the surreal, devouring chaos surrounding him--nor the only one who will be forced to accept a new role in this brave new world of nightmare and wonder. For the forces bled from the stilled machines are fueling a consciousness both newly born and ancient--and more than one unlikely hero will be needed for the titanic battle between the darkness and the light.
>
> This first collaboration between talented writers Marc Scott Zicree and Barbara Hambly is the beginning of an innovative fantasy series. An enthralling and entertaining read, Magic Time mixes supernatural forces and elements of classic epic-quest fantasy with modern technology and contemporary themes in a fascinating "What if?" scenario that presents a world where science is turned on its head as magical forces -- and strange new creatures -- blossom in its place.
>
> <sub>[Goodreads, *Magic Time*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1239560.Magic_Time)</sub>

Comment: You're a champion, that is it exactly!  I've been hunting this off and on for some time so I can't tell you how great it is to find it.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks to @TheLethalCarrot for adding the blurb.